# jquery mobile custom menu conflict with footer

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

Issue with jquery mobile custom select menu and the footer in IOS mobile devices(This works fine in emulators): 
1. The native select menu pops briefly on quick swipe of the menu. Next the Select menu finally loads. Then the footer disappears.
2. When a long custom select menu is displayed and a user scrolls down to the bottom and then closes the select menu, the footer is "floating" on the previous page

Note: The custom select menu works fine without the footer.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html

Example:
http://jsbin.com/utuxuv/1